# wget - download all files but not preceding folders

Tags: download, wget

I'm using wget to download all files from within a folder using the -r and -np options. However this also downloads the preceding folders, which I don't want.

For example:

```
wget -r -np ftp://user:pass@352.525.255.54/articles/artist/images/
```

this downloads all files from within "images" (which is good) but then also downloads the folders **articles**, **artist** and **images** (which is bad). What option fixes this?

Comment: (Off topic, not really about programming or software development, voting to move to SuperUser.)

Comment: @Bruno - Agreed

Comment: it is about software development - im writing an aspect FTP transfers within a piece of software

Answer (score 17):

I think what you are looking for is the `--cut-dirs` option.  Used in conjunction with the `-nH` (no hostname) option, you can specify exactly which level of directory you want to appear in your local output.  As an example, I have a .pkg download that I want to write to my local directory, and I don't want all of the parent tree to be included, just the subdirectories.  In this case, my starting point to just get the .pkg name as the parent directory is 5 levels down:

```
wget -np -nH --cut-dirs 5 -r http://www.myhost.org/pub/downloads/My_Drivers/OS_10_5_x/Letter_Format/driver_C123_105.pkg
```

What you will see, then, is the name driver_C123_105.pkg in your current directory.

```
% ls -lt | head
drwxr-xr-x   12 rob  rob        408 Feb 22 12:54 driver_C123_105.pkg
-rw-------@   1 rob  rob          0 Feb 16 15:59 1kPSXcUj.pdf.part
-rw-------@   1 rob  rob        842 Feb  3 14:47 WcUuL69s.jnlp.part
```

[...etc...]

```
% find driver_C123_105.pkg
driver_C123_105.pkg
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/Archive.bom
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/Archive.pax.gz
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/index.html
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/index.html?C=D;O=A
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/index.html?C=D;O=D
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/index.html?C=M;O=A
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/index.html?C=M;O=D
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/index.html?C=N;O=A
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/index.html?C=N;O=D
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/index.html?C=S;O=A
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/index.html?C=S;O=D
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/Info.plist
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/PkgInfo
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/Resources
driver_C123_105.pkg/Contents/Resources/background.jpg
```

[.....etc....]

You can direct this output to go elsewhere with the `-P` option.

Comment: -nH refers to `--no-host-directories`

Comment: This is exactly it! in my case, was downloading busybox binaries from their page.
`wget --no-parent --no-host-directories --cut-dirs 3 -r https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.30.0-i686/`to get everything inside the 1.30.0-i686 directory.

Answer (score 10):

The `--no-parent`-Option is what you are looking for.

Comment: The asker already knows about `--no-parent` — he used the short version `-np` in the example command. It's more likely that he's looking for the `--cut-dirs` option, as in [Robert Casey's answer](https://superuser.com/a/392942/112593).

Answer (score 4):

You might looking for this:

```
wget -r -np -nd ftp://user:pass@352.525.255.54/articles/artist/images/
```

The -nd switch is a short for --no-directories.

Comment: Stack Overflow, still quicker than reading manuals... thanks for your answer, exactly what I need :)

Comment: Note that with the `-nd` option, the **entire directory structure** will be discarded — so even if there are subdirectories below the one you're downloading, they won't be created, and all files will get saved to the root download directory.

Answer (score 0):

From `man wget`:

```
   -np
   --no-parent
       Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving
       recursively.  This is a useful option, since it guarantees that
       only the files below a certain hierarchy will be downloaded.
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. does it work for ftp too?

Comment: Not sure why it would go up the hierarchy at all with FTP, since it doesn't make sense to follow links there. Try perhaps with `--mirror`, or with a different FTP client (`lftp`, `ncftp`, ...)